# Libvirt event for disk change is not being registered by DomainEventRegisterAny()

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I am writing an application which would monitor the changes on the domain on the KVM hypervisor through libvirt events.

Recently I have upgraded my libvirt from 9.4 to 9.10 and I have this issue.

While de-registering for `DomainEventDiskChangeCallback`, I get a libvirt error saying

```
libvirtError: internal error domain event 2 not registered;
```

where 2 is the callbackid returned by `virConnectDomainEventRegisterAny()` for the disk change event type.

This error didn’t occur when I used libvirt 0.9.4-23.el6_2.6

Can you please enlighten me on the recent changes that has been made?

Also, is the diskchange event a part of the domains life cycle event?

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in what you do.
This was a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020376) which is now [fixed](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2013-October/msg00798.html).

Diskchange is not a lifecycle event as it has nothing to do with the domain being started, killed, stopped, rebooted, etc.